# Running a unit test from a console app is 5 times slower than from ReSharper

Tags: c#, performance, nunit, console-application, resharper

When running a NUnit test from ReSharper to calculate the second answer to [AdventOfCode.com day 23](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/23), the execution time is around 4 seconds. When running the same test from a console or windows application, the execution time is around 20 seconds. I can't figure out the cause of this difference.

**Environment:**

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 (Version 16.8.1)
- ReSharper 2020.2.1
- Windows 10 Pro (Version 10.0.18363.1198)
- Core i7-9750H 2.6 GHz, 16 GB RAM

**Project settings:**

- Release, Any CPU, Do **not** prefer 32-bit
- Console Application
- .NET Framework 4.8
- NUnit 3.12.0

A LinkedList and a LinkedListNode[] lookup table is allocated, both containing 1 000 000 elements. The following operations are then performed 10 000 000 times: 3 elements are removed and inserted at a different place in the linked list.

The unit test is contained within the console application and is either run using the ReSharper test runner from within Visual Studio (execution time 3.7-4.2 seconds). Or the console application is started, entering the Main() method which jst contains:

```
static void Main()
{
  new AoC_2020_23().D();
}
```

It doesn't matter if I start the console application from within Visual Studio, from a command prompt or from the Run item in the Windows Start menu. The execution time is around 20-22 seconds every time. The `Environment.Is64BitProcess` property is true regardless whether running the unit test or the console application.

Including the complete unit test for reference:

```
[Test]
public void D()
{
  Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  long result = RunB("853192647", 10 * 1000 * 1000);
  Console.WriteLine(result);
  Assert.AreEqual(664642452305, result);
  Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess + " " + timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.0"));
}

private long RunB(string input, int turns)
{
  int[] labels = input.Select(o => o - '0').ToArray();
  LinkedList<int> cups = new LinkedList<int>();
  LinkedListNode<int>[] lookup = new LinkedListNode<int>[1000 * 1000 + 1];
  foreach(int label in labels)
    lookup[label] = cups.AddLast(label);
  const int maximumLabel = 1000 * 1000;
  for(int cup = cups.Max() + 1; cup <= maximumLabel; cup++)
    lookup[cup] = cups.AddLast(cup);
  LinkedListNode<int> current = cups.First;

  for(int turn = 0; turn < turns; turn++)
  {
    PerformMovesB(cups, lookup, maximumLabel, ref current);
  }

  LinkedListNode<int> node = lookup[1].Next ?? cups.First;
  long a = node.Value;
  long b = (node.Next ?? cups.First).Value;
  return a * b;
}

private void PerformMovesB(LinkedList<int> cups, LinkedListNode<int>[] lookup, int maximumLabel, ref LinkedListNode<int> current)
{
  int currentLabel = current.Value;

  List<int> removed = new List<int>(3);
  LinkedListNode<int> node = current.Next ?? cups.First;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    lookup[node.Value] = null;
    removed.Add(node.Value);
    LinkedListNode<int> next = node.Next ?? cups.First;
    cups.Remove(node);
    node = next;
  }

  int search = currentLabel - 1;
  if(search < 1)
    search = maximumLabel;
  while(removed.Contains(search))
    if(--search < 1)
      search = maximumLabel;

  node = lookup[search];
  foreach(int label in removed)
    lookup[label] = node = cups.AddAfter(node, label);

  current = current.Next ?? cups.First;
}
```

Comment: Are both run types on the same hardware and OS? If not, check `Stopwatch` fields `Frequency` and `IsHighResolution`. Even if on same machine, maybe check anyway to be sure.

Comment: @Charlie They are run on the same computer. IsHighResolution = True, Frequency = 10 000 000 in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect anti-virus kicking in.  This is my hunch as Resharper might not spawn a new process to run your test in and usually anti-virus scanners will scan processes when they are launched (which is definitely the case when you run the console app).

Try setting up an explicit exclusion for the location that the console application is being launched from.